# Smooth Scroll to start in center?

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling

I'm using a scroll jquery plugin and the width of the scroll is the width of the browser so when I have less content width than the browser width, I want the content to start at the center of the browser.

Here's what I have for the amount of pixels it takes to center the content.

**JQUERY**

```
var totalWidth = 0;
$('.scrollableArea img').each(function(){
     totalWidth += parseInt($(this).width(), 10);
}); 

//totalWidth is the width of the content

var containWidth = $('#makeMeScrollable').width(); //browser width

containWidth /= 2;
totalWidth /= 2;
startWidth = containWidth - totalWidth;
```

Is there any way I can make it so the scroll content starts `startWidth` away from the left?

If there is less content width than there is browser width the rest of the scrollDiv is filled with 75px divs.

So the html looks like

**HTML**

```
<div class="scrollableArea">
   <img/>
   <img/>
   <img/>
   <div class="filler"/>
   <div class="filler"/>
   <div class="filler"/>
   <div class="filler"/>
   ...etc
</div>
```

Here is the plugin site http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/

Answer (score 0):

jQueryv1.8.3+ contains browser scroll effects built in.  You can utilize this built in functionality as follows:

```
$('.scrollableArea').scrollLeft(startWidth );
```

Here is the jQuery source provided:

```
// Create scrollLeft and scrollTop methods
jQuery.each( {scrollLeft: "pageXOffset", scrollTop: "pageYOffset"}, function( method, prop ) {
var top = /Y/.test( prop );

jQuery.fn[ method ] = function( val ) {
    return jQuery.access( this, function( elem, method, val ) {
        var win = getWindow( elem );

        if ( val === undefined ) {
            return win ? (prop in win) ? win[ prop ] :
                win.document.documentElement[ method ] :
                elem[ method ];
        }

        if ( win ) {
            win.scrollTo(
                !top ? val : jQuery( win ).scrollLeft(),
                 top ? val : jQuery( win ).scrollTop()
            );

        } else {
            elem[ method ] = val;
        }
    }, method, val, arguments.length, null );
};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Smooth Div Scroll has [a method called move](http://smoothdivscroll.com/publicMethods.html#move) with which you can make the scroller move the number of pixels that you specify.

So if you want it to scroll 100 pixels to the right you use the method like this:

```
$("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll("move", 100);
```

So if you have the position in pixels where you want it to start, you can make the move when the scroller has initialized. I haven't tested this code, but it should work with something along these lines:

```
$("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
    setupComplete: function(eventObj, data) {
        $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll("move", startWidth);
    }
});
```

I hope I understood your question correctly. :-)